# Why does python attach imported modules to the package?

Tags: python, import, module

Why does Python attach imported modules to the package? I know I shouldn't worry about this, but just wanted to know if there is any explanation. In the following case, my understanding was that importing `logging` would add it to the module namespace. So why add it to the package namespace as well?

```
$ tree -I *.pyc
.
├── pkga
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── modb.py
└── test.py

$ cat pkga/__init__.py
$
$ cat pkga/modb.py
import logging
import types


$ cat test.py 
import pkga.modb
import pprint
import sys

pprint.pprint(sorted([ x for x in sys.modules.keys() if x.startswith("pkg")]))

$ python test.py 
['pkga', 'pkga.logging', 'pkga.modb', 'pkga.types']
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.modules) is used as a cache for all imported modules in the interpreter, so it should contain all the modules imported regardless of the location they were imported from.

Edit: Thanks to the comments, I realized that I wasn't answering the real question, which is why `pkga.logging` and `pkga.types` are in the list?

As pointed out by @vikki, this prevents problems from happening when using the same module name as some other module in the standard library. For example if `logging.py` or `types.py` is created under `pkga` the keys of `sys.modules` won't change. However the values for `pkga.logging` and `pkga.types` won't be a standard module anymore, but the module implemented in that package.

Comment: But then why does it contain `pkga.logging` and `pkga.types` instead of just `logging` and `types`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams to retain the namespaces. if another module implements a class or function called `logging` then the application might crash because of confusion

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think vikki is right. If `logging.py` is created under `pkga`, `sys.modules` will have the same key, but `pkga.logging` would be a completely different module.

Comment: @vikki: How would what's in `sys.modules` confuse it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams okay assume another module called `logger` implements a `logging` function. If both `pkga.logging` and `logger.logging` are imported as `logging`, this would cause confusion in that python wouldn't know which `logging` to use if you call `pkga.logging.function` later in your application.

Comment: Why would you ever import both as the same name?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This is to answer the question why is `pkga` retained, this is so that python can differentiate modules/classes/functions that have the same name. When I said "imported as", I was talking about python itself and not the statement `from module import func as funky`